# Error : Failed to load PDF document using google cloud StorageOptions for SignUrl

Tags: java, playframework, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get PDF document from Web API using google cloud SignUrl, and want to show in app. Getting "**Error : Failed to load PDF document**".

**I follow for signurl :-** https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

This below code working fine for images file.

I try commented in code. 
Its code getting signurl for all files and pdf file also, but I am unable to figure out that how is it get pdf file for view?

Please go through my code:

**ControllerClass** :-

```
class ControllerClass{
    public Result show(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return redirect(mModelService.getSignedUrl(fileName));
        //   -- TRY other way to get pdf file.
        //return redirect(mModelService.getSignedUrl(userId,fileName));
        //                .withHeader("Content-Type","application/pdf");
        //                .as("application/octet-stream");
    }
}
```

**Get Signed Url :-**

```
public String getSignedUrl(String fileName) throws IOException {
String remotePath = filePath(fileName);
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("gcsBucket", remotePath);
    Blob blob =  getStorage().get(blobId);
    if(blob != null && blob.exists()){
        URL url = blob.signUrl(ttlMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES, SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
        );
        return url.toString();
}
```

**Get Storage :-**

```
public com.google.cloud.storage.Storage getStorage() {
    if(storage == null) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if(storage == null) {
                storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
            }
        }
    }
    return storage;
}


  //   -- TRY other way to get pdf file.
public String getSignedUrl(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(gcsBucket, remotePath);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId)
            /*.setContentType("application/doc")*/
            /*.setContentType("application/pdf")*/
            /*.setContentType("application/octet-stream")*/
            .build();
    URL url =  cloudStorageFactory.getStorage().signUrl(blobInfo,ttlMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES, SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
    //                    ,SignUrlOption.withContentType()
    );
    return url.toString();
}
```

Comment: you dont know how to send a PDF file, from controller to the views?you have a problem getting the file. or both? Where this error coming from? What is the error stack?

Comment: when getting the file.

Comment: does the file exist, in the first place? Which Java IO functionality you are using to get to it?

Comment: Yes, the file exist. Its not any IO for storing temprially file, its code using signup url, which direct show file valid show see this line:- 
 
    URL url =  cloudStorageFactory.getStorage().signUrl(blobInfo,ttlMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES, SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);